Проблема совместимости Vite и PUG
Подскажите, кто сталкивался с проблемой совместимости Vite и PUG?
При изменении кода в скрипте, все ломается и требуется перезагружать сервер, только потом запускается.
Проблема старая, не знаю как решить((

Этот вопрос похож на: PUG + VUE(2,3) + Quasar. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! не создавайте пожалуйста новые-одинаковые  вопросы, а редактируйте имеющийся. Вот справка, тут советы по созданию вопросов => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

может тут есть что можно почерпать ? => https://stackoverflow.com/q/76565215/13754729
